# Using the Mustache 'each' tag in Journey Builder Data Bindings

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mustache

I'm using the [C# Mustache template syntax](https://github.com/jehugaleahsa/mustache-sharp) (used by Journey Builder) to create Data Binding templates. I've tested the `if` tag and that works really well, but I can't figure out the syntax to use for the `each` tag.

I'm testing this by setting the `arguments` object in a `DataExtensionUpdate` (Update Contact Data) Activity to update a Data Extension with Attribute values from an Attribute Group. Here's what my `arguments` object looks like:

```
"arguments": {
"contactKey": "{{Contact.Key}}",
"value": "{{#each Contact}}{{Attribute.Members.Firstname}} {{Attribute.Members.Lastname}}, {{Attribute.Members.Company}}{{/each}}"
},
```

This is an alternative to declaring the fully qualified attribute name for each placeholder tag (which does work):

```
"arguments": {
    "contactKey": "{{Contact.Key}}",
    "value": "{{Contact.Attribute.Members.Firstname}} {{Contact.Attribute.Members.Lastname}}, {{Contact.Attribute.Members.Company}}"
},
```

I'd expect the Data Extension to be updated to with the Member Firstname Lastname and Company, for example:

> Sam Sample, Sample Company

I've tried different variations of the `each` syntax, including:

```
{{#each Contact.Attribute.Members}}{{Firstname}} {{Lastname}}, {{Company}}{{/each}}
```

And

```
{{#each Contact.Attribute}}{{Members.Firstname}} {{Members.Lastname}}, {{Members.Company}}{{/each}}
```

And

```
{{#each Contact}}{{Attribute.Members.Firstname}} {{Attribute.Members.Lastname}}, {{Attribute.Members.Company}}{{/each}}
```

With each syntax, the Contact fails at this Activity in the Interaction and I can see (using my browser Inspector) that there is an issue with the syntax:

```
Result-> Status = [Fail] Error: [ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Engine.DataBoundException: ExactTarget.JourneyBuilder.Activities.DataExtensionUpdateActivity.Value: Error binding data bound member. ---> ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Binding.EvaluatedExpressionException: Error rendering required expression [{{#each Contact}}{{Attribute.Members.Firstname}} {{Attribute.Members.Lastname}}, {{Attribute.Members.Company}}{{\\/each}}] value [] to data type [System.String]

at ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Binding.Evaluators.ExpressionEvaluator.Evaluate[T](String expression, WorkflowContext context, Activity activity, Boolean optional)

at ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Workflow.Activities.Binding.DataBound`1.DataBind(IExpressionEvaluator evaluator, WorkflowContext context, Activity activity, Boolean optional)

at ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Engine.EngineImpl.<>c__DisplayClass9.<BindData>b__8()

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Engine.EngineImpl.<>c__DisplayClass9.<BindData>b__8()
at ExactTarget.Diagnostics.StatsCollection.RecordMetric(String[] names, Action action)
at ExactTarget.Diagnostics.Stats.Time(String tag, Action action)
at ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Engine.EngineImpl.Process(EngineInstanceInfo instanceInfo)]
```

Can someone confirm if the `each` Mustache tag is supported by the Journey Builder engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the `each` tag is not supported, which after thinking this through makes sense as this would theoretically render values for each record in the Data Extension. To achieve what I wanted to do, I changed to the `with` tag and this works correctly:

```
"arguments": {
    "contactKey": "{{Contact.Key}}",
    "value": "{{#with Contact.Attribute.Members}}{{Firstname}} {{Lastname}}, {{Company}}{{/with}}"
},
```